# Add a custom linked text under WooCommerce single product meta, above share buttons

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce, product

How to add "contact us" text under the tag or above the share button on a single product page

I have added another text below the price of the product, it works

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 'bbloomer_show_return_policy', 20 );
 
function bbloomer_show_return_policy() {
    echo '<p class="rtrn">   See Our License <a href="mysite.com/license/" target="_blank"> Here! </a>
<br /></p>';
}
```

if to add text below the tag or above the share button it doesn't work

```
add_action (  'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button' , 'bbloomer_after_add_to_cart_btn'  ) ;
 
function bbloomer_after_add_to_cart_btn ( ) { 
        echo '<p class="rtrn">   Contact us <a href="mysite/contact-us/" target="_blank"> Here! </a>
<br /></p>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How to add “contact us” text under the tag or above the share button use the following:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_single_product_summary', 45 );
function custom_single_product_summary() {
    printf( '<p class="rtrn">%s<a href="%s" target="_blank"> %s </a><br /></p>',
    __( "Contact us", "woocommerce" ),
    home_url( '/contact-us/' ),
    __( "Here!", "woocommerce") );
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: is this text possible?

`__( "Contact us", "woocommerce" ),`

I changed the color in CSS

Comment: without disturbing this color

`add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 'bbloomer_show_return_policy', 20 );
 
function bbloomer_show_return_policy() {
    echo '<p class="rtrn">   See Our License <a href="mysite.com/license/" target="_blank"> Here! </a>
<br /></p>';
}`

Comment: `.rtrn {
 font-weight: bold;
 font-family: sans-serif; 
 font-size: 13px;
 font-style: italic;
 color:#000;
}`

Comment: function both

I want to change the color only for the text code you provided, not the second

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

This code is worked for me. Hope this will helps you.

```
//Add DIV end element after shop loop item
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'action_woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 10, 0);
function action_woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item( ) {
  echo "</a>";
 };
//Add DIV start element before shop loop item
add_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'action_woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 10, 0);
function action_woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item( ) {
   echo "<p class="rtrn">See Our License <a href="mysite.com/license/" target="_blank"> Here!";

};
```

Comment: I have tried your code, and it works on the store page, not on a single product page

Comment: I want to display text on page product single